# "No CD/DVD media found" error during Windows 7 installation 

Tags: windows-7, installation

Hello guys. I get a strange error when trying to install Windows 7. Please help me. The error is that my instalation disk, which works fine on my HP notebook, does not work properly on my Asus computer.

It starts fine and load the files, but after I  click on the button "Install now", it says that no CD/DVD media was found. Why? I have changed the priority on the BIOS setup, but it had no effect. How to solve it?

Comment: Is it a regular win-7 installation disk or did it come with your HP notebook?

Comment: regular  win 7 instalation disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several causes for this error, since it is a known good install disc, I would try loading the Sata drivers for the Asus prior to setup running by using the "load drivers" button.